# Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine '10.87.6.234' failed

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-application-firewall

I am trying to connect web application with web service but I get stuck with this error. I had done all the firewall settings but still getting the error when I debug my application.

[image]

Help me out of this..!

Comment: it seems you try to running VS remote debugger on different server (10.187.6.234). could you explain how you hosting the web application and web service?. and are you already installed the VS remote debugger on the server (10.187.6.234)

Comment: on local iss server